# Web development with CDN: Issue "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: javascript, cors, cdn

I am developing a web site with cocos2d-JS, basically a HTML doc with a JS file. Now I want to put my res files and JS file on a CDN server and put my HTML on my own server.
But now I have meet an issue: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". What should I do?

PS.(I do NOT want to add a Reverse Proxy cause it cost too much)

Comment: Add CORS configuration in your CDN service.

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" makes it sounds like an Ajax issue.  Are you trying to load these resources via Ajax?  If you load a JS file via a `<script>` tag, then there are no cross origin restrictions and you should be able to put such a script on pretty much any server.  But, if you try to load it with Ajax, there are origin restrictions.  Please show the actual code that triggers  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".